# How to remove Multiple tags if present

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an xml which may or may not produce multiple system number. It should keep only one value if system number and external ID are same.

input :

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<ns0:updatePersonCrossReference_Input xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/mdm/customer">
   <xsdLocal3:ListOfSwiPersonPublishIO xmlns:xsdLocal3="http://www.siebel.com/xml/SwiPersonPublishIO">
      <xsdLocal3:Contact>
         <xsdLocal3:IntegrationId>0100004568</xsdLocal3:IntegrationId>
         <xsdLocal3:ListOfCIFContactReference>
            <xsdLocal3:CIFContactReference>
               <xsdLocal3:SystemNumber>GCIS</xsdLocal3:SystemNumber>
               <xsdLocal3:SystemName>GCIS</xsdLocal3:SystemName>
               <xsdLocal3:ExternalId>1016</xsdLocal3:ExternalId>
            </xsdLocal3:CIFContactReference>
            <xsdLocal3:CIFContactReference>
               <xsdLocal3:SystemNumber>GCIS</xsdLocal3:SystemNumber>
               <xsdLocal3:SystemName>GCIS</xsdLocal3:SystemName>
               <xsdLocal3:ExternalId>1016</xsdLocal3:ExternalId>
            </xsdLocal3:CIFContactReference>
            <xsdLocal3:CIFContactReference>
               <xsdLocal3:SystemNumber>HOG</xsdLocal3:SystemNumber>
               <xsdLocal3:SystemName>HOG</xsdLocal3:SystemName>
               <xsdLocal3:ExternalId>2002</xsdLocal3:ExternalId>
            </xsdLocal3:CIFContactReference>
            <xsdLocal3:CIFContactReference>
               <xsdLocal3:SystemNumber>HOG</xsdLocal3:SystemNumber>
               <xsdLocal3:SystemName>HOG</xsdLocal3:SystemName>
               <xsdLocal3:ExternalId>2002</xsdLocal3:ExternalId>
            </xsdLocal3:CIFContactReference>
            <xsdLocal3:CIFContactReference>
               <xsdLocal3:SystemNumber>OCR</xsdLocal3:SystemNumber>
               <xsdLocal3:SystemName>OCR</xsdLocal3:SystemName>
               <xsdLocal3:ExternalId>3003</xsdLocal3:ExternalId>
            </xsdLocal3:CIFContactReference>
            <xsdLocal3:CIFContactReference>
               <xsdLocal3:SystemNumber>OCR</xsdLocal3:SystemNumber>
               <xsdLocal3:SystemName>OCR</xsdLocal3:SystemName>
               <xsdLocal3:ExternalId>3003</xsdLocal3:ExternalId>
            </xsdLocal3:CIFContactReference>
         </xsdLocal3:ListOfCIFContactReference>
      </xsdLocal3:Contact>
   </xsdLocal3:ListOfSwiPersonPublishIO>
</ns0:updatePersonCrossReference_Input>
```

output should be :

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<ns0:updatePersonCrossReference_Input xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/mdm/customer">
   <xsdLocal3:ListOfSwiPersonPublishIO xmlns:xsdLocal3="http://www.siebel.com/xml/SwiPersonPublishIO">
      <xsdLocal3:Contact>
         <xsdLocal3:IntegrationId>0100004568</xsdLocal3:IntegrationId>
         <xsdLocal3:ListOfCIFContactReference>
            <xsdLocal3:CIFContactReference>
               <xsdLocal3:SystemNumber>GCIS</xsdLocal3:SystemNumber>
               <xsdLocal3:SystemName>GCIS</xsdLocal3:SystemName>
               <xsdLocal3:ExternalId>1016</xsdLocal3:ExternalId>
            </xsdLocal3:CIFContactReference>            
            <xsdLocal3:CIFContactReference>
               <xsdLocal3:SystemNumber>HOG</xsdLocal3:SystemNumber>
               <xsdLocal3:SystemName>HOG</xsdLocal3:SystemName>
               <xsdLocal3:ExternalId>2002</xsdLocal3:ExternalId>
            </xsdLocal3:CIFContactReference>            
            <xsdLocal3:CIFContactReference>
               <xsdLocal3:SystemNumber>OCR</xsdLocal3:SystemNumber>
               <xsdLocal3:SystemName>OCR</xsdLocal3:SystemName>
               <xsdLocal3:ExternalId>3003</xsdLocal3:ExternalId>
            </xsdLocal3:CIFContactReference>            
         </xsdLocal3:ListOfCIFContactReference>
      </xsdLocal3:Contact>
   </xsdLocal3:ListOfSwiPersonPublishIO>
</ns0:updatePersonCrossReference_Input>
```

if input is :

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<ns0:updatePersonCrossReference_Input xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/mdm/customer">
   <xsdLocal3:ListOfSwiPersonPublishIO xmlns:xsdLocal3="http://www.siebel.com/xml/SwiPersonPublishIO">
      <xsdLocal3:Contact>
         <xsdLocal3:IntegrationId>0100004568</xsdLocal3:IntegrationId>
         <xsdLocal3:ListOfCIFContactReference>
            <xsdLocal3:CIFContactReference>
               <xsdLocal3:SystemNumber>GCIS</xsdLocal3:SystemNumber>
               <xsdLocal3:SystemName>GCIS</xsdLocal3:SystemName>
               <xsdLocal3:ExternalId>1016</xsdLocal3:ExternalId>
            </xsdLocal3:CIFContactReference>            
            <xsdLocal3:CIFContactReference>
               <xsdLocal3:SystemNumber>HOG</xsdLocal3:SystemNumber>
               <xsdLocal3:SystemName>HOG</xsdLocal3:SystemName>
               <xsdLocal3:ExternalId>2002</xsdLocal3:ExternalId>
            </xsdLocal3:CIFContactReference>            
            <xsdLocal3:CIFContactReference>
               <xsdLocal3:SystemNumber>OCR</xsdLocal3:SystemNumber>
               <xsdLocal3:SystemName>OCR</xsdLocal3:SystemName>
               <xsdLocal3:ExternalId>3003</xsdLocal3:ExternalId>
            </xsdLocal3:CIFContactReference>            
         </xsdLocal3:ListOfCIFContactReference>
      </xsdLocal3:Contact>
   </xsdLocal3:ListOfSwiPersonPublishIO>
</ns0:updatePersonCrossReference_Input>
```

Then output should display the same.

Any inputs appreciated. I am using XSL 1.0.

Thanks,
M S

Comment: You can use Muenchian's grouping to group `CIFContactReference` by `SystemNumber` and `ExternalId`.

Comment: "*I am using XSL 1.0.*" Then don't tag your question as `xslt-2.0`.  -- As others have noted, the answer for XSLT 1.0 can be found here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html and in the numerous SO answers that are tagged  `xslt-1.0` and `grouping`

Comment: Thanks Michael and Lingamurthy. Its done !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muenchian grouping, i.e.

(Just typed in without syntax checking, but should sthg. like this.)

1. create a compound index for CIFContactReference, sth. like

(I used to add a foreign character, say '_', for separation of keys, when no. and id are variable length and merge may be duplicated.)

2. then make a for-each for cleanup within  xsdLocal3:ListOfCIFContactReference,

check if the first of the nodes with the same key (i.e. key('ref',$keyValue)[1]) has the same id as the actual one (then this is the first in the list).

This is much much faster in most cases than following-sibling::xsdLocal3:CIFContactReference[...]) checking; however, if your list is composed of 1-2 elements only, the following-sibling could be still somewhat faster.